# Is it possible to do adaptive learning(online learning) in Recurrent Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, prediction, supervised-learning

Is it possible to do adaptive learning(online learning) in Recurrent Neural Networks for(newelm)? The weight won't update itself and I didn't see any improvement.

If yes, how it is possible, which functions should I use?

```
net = newelm(threshold,[6, 8, 90],{'tansig','tansig', 'purelin'});
net.trainFcn               = 'trains';
batch_size                 = 10;
while(1)
       net = train(net,Pt(:, k:k+batch_size ) , Tt(:, k:k+batch_size)   );
end
```